# No logind.conf file in /etc/systemd/ in Ubuntu 20

Tags: suspend, 20.04, lock-screen, systemd-logind

My laptop does not suspend when I close the lid. Instead, when I open it, it freezes for around 5 seconds and continues working without asking for a password. So I checked online for a solution but every solution ends up in editing the "logind.conf" file in /etc/systemd/ .

However, there is no such file in my laptop.
All I have are these files/folders in the systemd folder:

`journald.conf  network  networkd.conf  pstore.conf  resolved.conf  sleep.conf  system  system.conf  timesyncd.conf  user  user.conf`

Comment: What is Ubuntu 20? I have this file.

Comment: By Ubuntu 20, I refer to the latest 20.04 version. Since this problem started happening after the update.

Comment: You can always create this file it it is missing for some reason.